# RSA Key generation Public exponent too big

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm currently writing a paper about RSA (a self-chosen subject).
I'm writing about the key-generation in RSA, and I have problem finding the public exponent *e*.

I have chosen *p = 61* and *q = 53*.

Then I determined my modulus *n = p ⋅ q = 3233*

and my *phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = 3120*.

What bothers me is that when I try to generate the public exponent *e* using [CrypTool](http://www.cryptool.org/en/download-ct1-en) (given the same parameters), it gives me *e = 2^16+1 = 65537* **BUT** I thought *e* had to be less that *phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)* (according to this [source](https://sites.google.com/site/danzcosmos/the-rsa-algorithm)).
Why is it OK to break this rule? Or is the CrypTool faulty?

Comment: Use $e = 3$, it should work. But this small primes offer no security at all, so only use these as an example, and please make clear that in real-live systems the primes must be much larger.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann $e = 3$ won't work here, $\varphi{(n)}$ is a multiple of 3.

Comment: For an introduction, $e=17$ will do: it is actually used, and the audience will grab that $x^{17}\bmod n$ can be computed as $((((x^2)^2)^2)^2)⋅x\bmod n$; will be able to do that for small $x$; then find that for bigger $x$ they want to $((((x^2\bmod n)^2\bmod n)^2\bmod n)^2\bmod n)⋅x\bmod n$. Also, the audience may be less intimidated by $1=e⋅d\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(p−1,q−1)$ than by $d=e^{-1}\bmod{φ(n)}$, with the extra benefit for the former that it is the industry standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $2^{16} + 1$ exponent is really meant for use in real life systems, in which public keys are expected to be considerably larger than that. I guess CrypTool assumes this is the case, as you would expect, really.

That said, if $\gcd{(e, \varphi{(n)})} = 1$, then $gcd{(e ~ \mathrm{mod} ~ \varphi{(n)}, \varphi{(n)})} = 1$ by definition, so such an $e$ will still work regardless, as noted by fgrieu in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Really helped me :)
And yes, I am aware of public keys being that small are very insecure, but I'm just using them as an example in my paper.

Comment: @fgrieu Oh, yes, you are correct, stupid me. I will fix the answer.

Comment: RSA "works" as long as $n=p⋅q$ with $p$, $q$ distinct odd primes, $e$ coprime with $p−1$ and $q−1$ (thus $e$ odd), and $e⋅d≡1\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p−1,q−1)}$; then, $x↦x^e\bmod n$ and $x↦x^d\bmod n$ are reverse permutations of $[0,n−1]$. It is immaterial that $e<φ(n)$, though usual $e$ are smalller, and [PKCS#1v2.1](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) wants $e<n$. Any $e'≡e\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p−1,q−1)}$ is equivalent to $e$, and odd. The [first RSA-like cryptosystem](http://cryptocellar.web.cern.ch/cryptocellar/cesg/ellis.pdf) used $e=n$. [Take five]

Comment: But if e is too small, and you don't pad correctly, it will be insecure.